# IPPL with Matlab Compiler Runtime (MCR)

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I'm trying to deploy an application from Matlab to JAVA.
I use Matlab Builder JA and the Image Processing Toolbox.
I create my jar file from Matlab R2012a with the deploytool on MacOSX.

When I run my JAVA program using this jar on my mac, it's OK, but when I try to run it on a Linux or Windows system, I get the error:

Undefined function or variable 'ipplmex'.
Error in ==> ippl at 48
Error in ==> imrotate>useIPP at 205

Deactivating the use of IPPL with iptsetpref('UseIPPL', false) doesn't fix my problem.

I also have done the exact same work on a Linux environment with Matlab R2011a, and it works on Linux but not on a MacOSX machine with the same error.

If anyone has an idea concerning this IPPL thing when changing OS, that would be great.

Thanks !

Comment: I wonder if the version of IPPL deployed in each environment is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java components created with Builder JA are only cross-platform if they don't depend on platform-specific libraries, such as MEX-files you create, or the IPPL libraries supplied with Image Processing Toolbox.

If you want your Java component to make use of IPPL, I think you'll need to create the Java component once on Mac, once on Linux, once on Windows, and use the version created on the appropriate platform.

`ipplmex` is a (platform-specific) MEX file that is called by `ippl`, which is a utility function that checks whether IPPL is available. I can't check this at the moment, but I think it makes that availability check whether or not you've specified that you want to actually use IPPL, via the `iptsetpref` command. Therefore whether or not you specify that IPPL should be used, there's still a platform-specific MEX-file being called.

Again, I can't check this at the moment, but if you're comfortable with your component not using IPPL, you might try to modify the `ippl` command to just return zero (indicating that IPPL is not available) without attempting to execute `ipplmex`. (Make sure to take a copy of your existing `ippl.m` file before you try any modifications).